# Regex, get all hyperlinks

Tags: java, regex

I try to figure out how to get 2 matches from String `Bla bla bla [https://google.com|Google] bla bla bla [https://youtube.com|Youtube]`

I want to get 2 matches: `[https://google.com|Google], [https://youtube.com|Youtube]`.
My regex looks likee this: `\[.*\|.*\]` and with it I get only one match: `[https://google.com|Google] bla bla bla [https://youtube.com|Youtube]` so it is wrong answer. How to get the right answer?

P.S. google and youtube - the hardcoded example. I get array of data with 1000+ entries, so I need a universal solution.

Comment: `.*` is greedy. Make it reluctant by adding `?` like `.*?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```java
\[([^\]\[|]*)\|([^\]\[]*)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HRLCGl/1). Details:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\]\[|]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `|`
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Group 2: any  zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

In Java, use

```java
String regex = "\\[([^\\]\\[|]*)\\|([^\\]\\[]*)]";
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/eBKKLT):

```java
String s = "Bla bla bla [https://google.com|Google] bla bla bla [https://youtube.com|Youtube]";
String regex = "\\[([^\\]\\[|]*)\\|([^\\]\\[]*)]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println("Group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```java
Match: [https://google.com|Google]
Group 1: https://google.com
Group 2: Google
Match: [https://youtube.com|Youtube]
Group 1: https://youtube.com
Group 2: Youtube
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But also it was needed to add https to the first capture group

Comment: @MikhailGulyaev Миша, `https` is present in the matches. If you mean it must be part of the pattern, just add it, `\[(https[^\]\[|]*)\|([^\]\[]*)]`

Answer (score 0):

u need to make quantifier ***** lazy by adding **?** mark , here is an example :

```
String  s = "Bla bla bla [https://google.com|Google] bla bla bla [https://youtube.com|Youtube]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);

while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
[https://google.com|Google]
[https://youtube.com|Youtube]
```